# MVC: Iterating a Viewbag array in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays, razor, viewbag

The goal is to get the data from the `ViewBag.Array` to a Javascript array. The data is calculated in the controller so I cannot fetch it straight from the database. I need the data to draw a chart with jqplot. Code:

```
for(i = 0; i < @ViewBag.Array.Length; i++)
{
    jScriptArray[i] = @ViewBag.Array[i];
}
```

The problem is "'i' does not exist in the current context" in the `@ViewBag.Array[i]` but has no problems in the `jScriptArray[i]`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.Array));
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    jScriptArray[i] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: How about a two dimensional array? Using this technique it ends up one dimensional.

Comment: @JohnMeyer did you figure out a way to work with two dimension viewbag array yet?

Comment: I think I ended up passing it to the view on the model instead of using the ViewBag.

Comment: in my case it was `Json.Serialize` instead of `Json.Encode`

Answer (score 2):

```
var array=@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.Array));
```

**you can make use of JsonConvert.SerializeObject**
Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var jScriptArray=[];
@{
    for(i = 0; i < ViewBag.Array.Length; i++){
      <text>jScriptArray[@i] = "@ViewBag.Array[@i]";</text>
      i++;
    }
  }
</script>
```

You will end up with something like this in html file:

```
jScriptArray[0] = "ArrayValue0";
jScriptArray[1] = "ArrayValue1";
jScriptArray[2] = "ArrayValue2";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve your goal is to create a JSON controller that returns the data into a JSON array.

From your javascript you can request the data and then process it.

Hope this helps

Comment: No, this [can be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830549/mvc-iterating-a-viewbag-array-in-javascript/5830594#5830594). No need to create a controller returning JSON for this.

Comment: Sorry for the can't be done, but it s better to use a JSON controller than using Viewbag for javascript server-side communication.

Comment: for `javascript -> server` communication yes, it's better, I agree. But here we are talking about `server -> javascript` communication. The server already sent a view model to the view, it would be bad to perform an additional AJAX request just to JSON serialize this model when this can be done directly.