# asp.net mvc display ViewBag dictionary to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm new in C# asp.net mvc. I'm making a ViewBag that contains Dictionary data type in controller and i want to get and display the value by javascript in .cshtml to code it with googlemaps function.

here's my dictionary & viewbag code from the controller:

```
Dictionary<string, string> alamatVehicleMarker = new Dictionary<string, string>();
alamatVehicleMarker.Add("v1","Bali");
alamatVehicleMarker.Add("v2","Jakarta");
alamatVehicleMarker.Add("v3","Bandung");

ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle = alamatVehicleMarker;
```

can you help me how to get the ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle in  and how to loop through it please

**EDITED**

i've tried this :

```
<script>
function GetViewBagDictionary(id) {

            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle)
            {
                var key = item.Key;
                var Value = item.Value;

                if (key == id)
                {
                    return Value;
                }
            }

            return "not found";
        }
<script>
```

but inside the if function it's give a error said that : `The name 'id' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Are you just asking how to loop over a dictionary?  A casual Google search immediately found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-c

Comment: @David i'm sorry i mean i need to loop it in javascript because i want to use it in google maps function, i've edited my question i'm sorry

Comment: @Shasapo Please try my answer and see if it works or not.

Comment: @kolunar yes i've tried it too and it works :D thank you so much for your solution and answer :D i really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work **just be careful of the datatypes**, put this in the cshtml.

```
var dictionary = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle));
for(var key in dictionary ){
    var value = dictionary[key];
    console.log(value);
}
```

Resources:

[Html Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

[Json Encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.json?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I convert VeiwBag into javascript's ViewBag object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ViewBag = {
    IsDesigner: ("@ViewBag.IsDesigner").toLowerCase() === 'true',
    IsAdmin: ("@ViewBag.IsAdmin").toLowerCase() === 'true',
    EmptyGuid: "@ViewBag.EmptyGuid",
    Advertisers_ID: "@ViewBag.Advertisers_ID",
    Primary_Category: "@ViewBag.Primary_Category",
    Primary_Category_ID: "@ViewBag.Primary_Category_ID",
    Advertiser_Name: "@ViewBag.Advertiser_Name",
    Advertiser_NameMM: "@ViewBag.Advertiser_NameMM",
    BookTypeName: "@ViewBag.BookTypeName",
    getAlamatVehicle: { 
        @{
            int marker_count = 0;
            string markers_str = "";                
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle) 
            {
                markers_str += "\"" + item.Key + "\": \"" + item.Value + "\"";
                marker_count++;
                if (marker_count < ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle.Count)
                {
                    markers_str += ", ";
                }
            }
            var html_str = new HtmlString(markers_str);
        }
        @html_str
    }
}
console.log(ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle);
</script>
```

Result:

```
var ViewBag = {
    IsDesigner: ("False").toLowerCase() === 'true',
    IsAdmin: ("True").toLowerCase() === 'true',
    EmptyGuid: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    Advertisers_ID: "7e49def2-3887-4149-b419-5f1f51d4ec58",
    Primary_Category: "Construction Services",
    Primary_Category_ID: "ca9381c7-0379-4a72-80df-270287954164",
    Advertiser_Name: "Dolphin Ayeyarwady Pile Construction Co., Ltd.",
    Advertiser_NameMM: "",
    BookTypeName: "YD",
    getAlamatVehicle: { 
        "v1": "Bali", "v2": "Jakarta", "v3": "Bandung"
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Object {v1: "Bali", v2: "Jakarta", v3: "Bandung"}
```

Here's how you can implement the function:

```
function GetViewBagDictionary(id) {
    if (ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle.hasOwnProperty(id))
        return ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle[id];
    return "not found";
}
console.log(GetViewBagDictionary("v2"));
```

Console:

```
Jakarta
```

Test:

```
console.log(GetViewBagDictionary("v4"));
```

Console:

```
not found
```

Comment: thankyou so much for your answer, i've tried it too and your solution it's works :D

Answer (score 1):

Please try foreach loop in javascript.

```
         function GetViewBagDictionary() {

            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.getAlamatVehicle)
             {
                 var key = item.Key;
                 var Value = item.Value;
             }


            }
```

[image: sample screen]

Comment: hi ponmani i've tried your answer but help me pls, i've got another problem, please check my edited question

Comment: hi @shaspo ..what  is going to do in if loop ? wats the purpose

Comment: @Shasapo.. check this link. which may be helpfule for u..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706603/the-name-controlname-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: in my google maps function it's only have the id : v1/v2/v3/v4/v5. and i want to  get the address value(Bali/Bandung/Jakarta) in dictionary, by comparing the id and the key from dictionary. and if it's not in the dictionary i want it to return "not found"

Comment: @Shasapo.. That is issue while using foreach . try for loop.  refer linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830549/mvc-iterating-a-viewbag-array-in-javascript

Comment: thankyou for your answer and solution for my question :D i've tried the last link you gave me and it's similar from J newton answer :D