# Cannot iterate a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            for (var i=0;i<@Model.listsinfo.Count;i++)
            {
                $('#work').append($('<div class="col-md-3" id="temp"><label for="text1">'+ '@Model.listsinfo[i].Label' +'</label></div><div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" placeholder="Alerts" class="form-control" id="text1"> </div>'));
            }
       }
   </script>
```

In the above code, I am passing a list from my controller and trying to iterate it. But **@Model.listsinfo[i].Label** is not working and the error says 'i' does not exist in the current context. I am able to access the list value by giving index values **@Model.listsinfo[0].Label** but iterations are not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: remove the single quotes from `'@Model.listsinfo[i].Label'`

Comment: Your `@Model.listsinfo` is located on server and your loop - on client

Comment: @Flying it's possible to access them in razor

Comment: @Niladri ok, my bad, sorry :)

Comment: @CRA try `console.log(@Model.listsinfo.Count)` and if the count is showing  inside the function

Comment: JS variable can't be used to mention `@Model.listsinfo` array index - they're both different (server-side vs client-side processing). You need to insert `@Model.listinfo` into JS array & iterate from there.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto there is a better in built way to iterate them in razor using foreach

Comment: or you can set them to any JS array and iterate it

Comment: @Niladri - It is a string value so using single quotes. (also tried removing them, not working :( ). Also the Count is working fine. I am facing issues in iteration. Thanks for the comments :)

Comment: @Niladri - Cannot use them  setting to a JS array bro :(

Comment: Razor works on the server to generate some text. When this generating is done, this text is sent to the browser where it is interpreted as HTML+Javascript. So Razor and Javascript run at very different times and cannot interact.

Comment: Why use a Javascript event to generate HTML instead of letting Razor generate that HTML for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Json.Encode` with `Html.Raw` and assign it to a JavaScript array, then iterate the contents from there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
            var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.listsinfo));

            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                $('#work').append($('<div class="col-md-3" id="temp"><label for="text1">'+ array[i].Label +'</label></div><div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" placeholder="Alerts" class="form-control" id="text1"> </div>'));
            }
    }
</script>
```

Note that `Model.listinfo` processed at server-side and iteration occurs in client-side, so you need to convert viewmodel array to JS array first, then you can assign it to `append` method.

Similar issues:

[MVC: Iterating a Viewbag array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830549/mvc-iterating-a-viewbag-array-in-javascript)

[jQuery: How to traverse / Iterate over a list of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730055/jquery-how-to-traverse-iterate-over-a-list-of-object)

Comment: You can consider to accept any answer that best solving your problem rather than saying "thanks", there's no obligation to do so.