# Loading ViewBag data into a chart.js multichart

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, chart.js, viewbag

I am trying to load in data from two Viewbags one containing data for a barchart and the other containing data for a linechart both of which contain data from a database query the code that I am using is shown below:

```
var outcomeData = "@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.ChartOutput)";
var avgDaysUseData = "@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.AvgDaysUseChartOutput)";
var outcomeArray = outcomeData.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").replace(/\'/g, "").split(',');
var avgDaysUseArray = avgDaysUseData.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "").replace(/\'/g, "").split(',');
var reportingPeriods = [];
var outcomeNames = [];
var outcomeValues = [];
var avgDaysUseValues = [];

    $.each(avgDaysUseArray,
        function (index, value) {
            if (Number.isNaN(value) === false) {
                value = parseFloat(value);
                avgDaysUseValues.push(value);
            }
        });

    $.each(outcomeArray,
        function (index, value) {
            var reportingPeriod = new RegExp('\\d{4}(\/)\\d{2}');
            var isReportingPeriod = reportingPeriod.test(value);
            if (isReportingPeriod) {
                reportingPeriods.push(value);
            }
            else {
                var outcomeName = new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]');
                var isOutcomeName = outcomeName.test(value);
                if (isOutcomeName) {
                    if (value !== "Outcomes") {
                        outcomeNames.push(value);
                    }
                } else {
                    value = parseInt(value);
                    outcomeValues.push(value);
                }
            }
        });

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

    var outcomeChart = new Chart(ctx,
        {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: reportingPeriods,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: 'line', fill: false, lineTension: 0,
                        label: 'Average days of use at start',
                        data: [avgDaysUseValues[4], avgDaysUseValues[7], avgDaysUseValues[10]],
                        yAxisId: 'y-axis-1',
                        borderColor: 'Black',
                        backgroundColor: 'Black',
                        borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'line', fill: false, lineTension: 0,
                        label: 'Average days of use at review',
                        data: [avgDaysUseValues[5], avgDaysUseValues[8], avgDaysUseValues[11]],
                        yAxisId: 'y-axis-1',
                        borderColor: 'Blue',
                        backgroundColor: 'Blue',
                        borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: outcomeNames[0],
                        data: [outcomeValues[0], outcomeValues[4], outcomeValues[8]],
                        yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
                        borderColor: '#FF9900',
                        backgroundColor: '#FF9900',
                        borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: outcomeNames[1],
                        data: [outcomeValues[1], outcomeValues[5], outcomeValues[9]],
                        yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
                        borderColor: '#FF6400',
                        backgroundColor: '#FF6400',
                        borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: outcomeNames[2],
                        data: [outcomeValues[2], outcomeValues[6], outcomeValues[10]],
                        yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
                        borderColor: '#FF0000',
                        backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
                        borderWidth: 2
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'bar',
                        label: outcomeNames[3],
                        data: [outcomeValues[3], outcomeValues[7], outcomeValues[11]],
                        yAxisID: 'y-axis-2',
                        borderColor: '#9A0033',
                        backgroundColor: '#9A0033',
                        borderWidth: 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: { scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Reporting Period', fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        position: 'bottom',
                        ticks: { fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        barPercentage: 0.95,
                        categoryPercentage: 0.15
                    }
                ],
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Average no. of days', fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        position: 'right', id: 'y-axis-1', type: 'linear',
                        ticks: { min: 0, beginAtZero: true, max: 28 },
                        gridLines: {display: true}
                    },
                    {
                        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'No. of clients', fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        position: 'left', id: 'y-axis-2',type: 'linear',
                        gridLines: { display: false }
                    }]
            },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    display: true,
                    onClick: null,
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: '#000000'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    outcomeChart.aspectRatio = 0;


    $('#chart').bind('contextmenu',
        function(e) {
            return false;
        });
```

I have provided a working example in a codepen to show what is being produced and how I want it to look, the example data I have provided in codepen is what is contained in the ViewBag:

https://codepen.io/gameloregeek/pen/GPXBdp

How do I use the data in the two viewbags to create a multichart like the example in codepen?

---

as examples here is the format of the data in each viewbag:

**Bar chart data**

```
var outcomeData = "['Outcomes','Abstinent','Improved','Unchanged','Deteriorated'],['2015/16',18036,11414,14430,1880],['2016/17',17642,11688,14010,1738],['2017/18',17282,10796,13542,1686]";
```

**Line chart data**

```
var avgDaysUseData = "['year','AvgDaysUseAtStart','AvgDaysUseAtReview'],['2015/16',21.6,8.3],['2016/17',22.2,8.5],['2017/18',22.1,8.6]";
```

---

Have revised my code but I can't use the Json Encoded data as it contains values that include forward slashes which are being interpreted as escape values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var outcomeData = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.ChartOutput))";
    var avgDaysUseData = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.AvgDaysUseChartOutput))";
    outcomeArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < outcomeData.length; i++) {
        outcomeArray[i] = outcomeData[i];
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

    var outcomeChart = new Chart(ctx,
        {
            type: 'bar',
            data: outcomeArray,
            options: { scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Reporting Period', fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        position: 'bottom',
                        ticks: { fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        barPercentage: 0.95,
                        categoryPercentage: 0.15
                    }
                ],
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Average no. of days', fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        position: 'right', id: 'y-axis-1', type: 'linear',
                        ticks: { min: 0, beginAtZero: true, max: 28 },
                        gridLines: {display: true}
                    },
                    {
                        scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: '@Model.XAxis', fontStyle: 'italic' },
                        position: 'left', id: 'y-axis-2',type: 'linear',
                        gridLines: { display: false }
                    }]
            },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    display: true,
                    onClick: null,
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: '#000000'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    outcomeChart.aspectRatio = 0;


    $('#chart').bind('contextmenu',
        function(e) {
            return false;
        });
</script>
```

the data after encoding looks like this:

```
 var outcomeData = ""[\u0027Outcomes\u0027,\u0027Abstinent\u0027,\u0027Improved\u0027,\u0027Unchanged\u0027,\u0027Deteriorated\u0027],[\u00272015/16\u0027,18036,11414,14430,1880],[\u00272016/17\u0027,17642,11688,14010,1738],[\u00272017/18\u0027,17282,10796,13542,1686]"";
```

and the error in the console is as follow **SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence**

Comment: All the chart code you've included is irrelevant - you only need to know how to convert your `ViewBag.ChartOutput` into the format that you've already determined works (not included here, but in the codepen) `"['Outcomes','Abstinent','Improved','Unchanged','Deteriorated'],['2015/16',18036,11414,14430,1880],['2016/17',17642,11688,14010,1738],['2017/18',17282,10796,13542,1686]"` which looks like an array of arrays.  So will depend on what format the `ChartOutput` takes.

Answer (score 1):

**If it is an C# Array in the ViewBag:**

```
var outcomeData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.ChartOutput));
```

use `Json.Encode` and `Html.Raw`

*Usefull Links:*

- Check this for more information:
  [MVC: Iterating a Viewbag array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830549/mvc-iterating-a-viewbag-array-in-javascript)
- Or this for a 2D array if thats important for you: [Pass 2D
  array from Controller Viewbag to JS](https://forums.asp.net/t/2133629.aspx?How%20to%20pass%202D%20array%20from%20Controller%20Viewbag%20to%20Javascript%20View%20for%20J%20Chart%20drawing)

---

**If it is a String in the Viewbag:** 
You can use the value from the ViewBag in JS like this:

```
var outcomeData = '@ViewBag.ChartOutput';
```

then you dont need the `Html.Raw`

Comment: does the data in the viewbags need to be in a particular format for chart.js to produce a chart?

Comment: will add the current formats to the question as examples

Comment: it has to be like you provided in the codepen (2D Array)

Comment: the viewbags contain C# Arrays but when I json encode them chart.js is giving me errors

Comment: when I JSON Encode the console is producing the error 
SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence